# How to solve this equation given another equation with the same variable

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Please help me. I've tried for quite a while but I do not know how to get the correct expression. The answer is 2 according to the markscheme.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that $$a^3-\frac {1}{a^3} = (a-\frac {1}{a})^3+3(a-\frac {1}{a})=8+6=14$$

Also $$a^2+\frac{1}{a^2} = (a-\frac {1}{a})^2+2=6$$

Thus $$a^3-\frac {1}{a^3} -2(a^2+\frac{1}{a^2})=14-2(6)=2$$

Answer (score 3):

$ a - \frac{1}{a} = 2$ implies that $a^{2} - 1 = 2a$; which equates to the quadratic equation $a^{2} - 2a - 1 = 0$, having solutions $a = 1 \pm \sqrt{2}$. Now, substitute into the other equation and evaluate.

Comment: I do not think this is the way the problem wants me to solve the question. I know I can just solve for "a" and then plug it into the other equation. Moreover, plugging this expression would also yield "extensive" work which is one of the reasons you did not do it. Nonethless, thanks for the answer.